# Launchctl List - Screen Sharing Process Running While Disabled?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, launchd, screen-sharing

Below is my list of active processes as produced by the `launchctl list` command in terminal. I'm not messing with those processes, but I am studying them to learn more about how OS X works.

The question that I have for you is why com.apple.screensharing.agent, com.apple.screensharing.messagessent, etc., are loaded when I have screen sharing disabled in settings.

A careful review of the list below and some assistance identifying anything odd or unusual is appreciated. I want zero ability, whatsoever, to SSHD, screen share, file share, remote access, etc. I've no need for it, and I don't like the fact that these processes are running when I intentionally have them disabled.

Little Snitch keeps showing a million different connection attempts, and I'm freaking tired of googling the ports and IP information with no clarity whatsoever. I've included a list of my LSN3 rules.

Comment: Nevermind about the list. Apparently the brilliant site coders think three pages of OS X system processes look like "spam." Because 99% of the SPAM I receive every day is system process lists. Makes a lot of sense, eh, site masters?

Comment: Remove any personal things in the list, upload it @pastebin and relink it here, please